# Null entry for Flask SelectField and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm building a Flask app with a PostgreSQL DB. I'm having trouble getting new data added to the database. The problem is with the Flask SelectField. I've set the "nullable" attribute to False, and the only choices are "male" and "female". The query generates an error "sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError" saying the gender column has a null value yet is selected before submission.

Here is the code snippet from models.py:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    gender = db.Column(db.String(7))
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable = False, unique=True, index=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
```

And this here is the snippet the markup:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      {{ form.gender.label() }}
      {{ form.gender( class="form-control" ) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Form code:

```
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    ...
    gender = SelectField('Gender', validators=[DataRequired()], 
                         choices=[('male','Male'),('female','Female')], coerce=str)
```

This here is the screenshot for the selectfield:

[gender SelectField](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFkLC.png)

Am I making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: What is the definition for the field in the form? Are you sure the field selection is getting back to the view? In other words does it show up in `request.form`?

Comment: Here is the snippet I forgot to add from forms.py
`class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):

    ...
    gender = SelectField('Gender', validators=[DataRequired()], choices=[('male','Male'),('female','Female')], coerce=str)`

Comment: Added form code to question. Also have you verified what is showing up in `request.form`?

Comment: Your question was just the trigger I needed to get to the bottom of this. I noticed I did not perform a `form.gender.data` in my view function. That was the source of the bug. So the query was performed with a null entry for the gender field. Thanks Adrian!